# Is it possible to parameterize a generic type with a value instead of a type?

Tags: swift

I'm looking for a way in Swift to create a new type specialization with a parameter that is a value, not a type itself, similar to how you'd do this with a C++ std::array (which specifies the fixed length of the array -- an int -- as part of the type itself).

For example, I want something like `Foo<5>` to be a distinct type from `Foo<6>`. That numeric parameter value would then affect its behavior. You could argue that I should just instantiate the type itself with a constant, but then that would be an actual object, not a type. Suppose I want to have an enum of cases where the associated values are these specialized types, for example.

From what I can tell, this common tool in C++ is not available in Swift; are there alternative approaches?

Comment: The feature you're looking for is called "dependent types" and is not available in Swift. NSHipster has a nice discussion comparing property wrappers to dependent types: https://nshipster.com/propertywrapper/ There's also an interesting (but not highly useful) discussion of using a phantom-like type to fake dependent types: https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2015-09-06-dependent-types.html

Answer (score 2):

You can't define a generic type using an integer or any other value and the closes I can think of is to use a protocol with implmentatins defining different values so that 5 and 6 can be different types.

Not sure if this is what your after but here is my example

```
protocol Size {
    static var size: Int { get }
}

struct Five: Size {
    static var size = 5
}
struct Six: Size {
    static var size = 6
}
```

And an example type that uses it

```
struct TypeWithSize<Element, N: Size> {
    var array: [Element]

    init(with value: Element) {
        array = Array(repeating: value, count: N.size)
    }
}
```

And then this type could be used in a `switch` based on the type

```
let five: TypeWithSize<Int, Five> = TypeWithSize(with: 1)
let six:  TypeWithSize<String, Six> = TypeWithSize(with: "A")

let array: [Any] = [five, six]

for value in array {
    switch value {
    case is TypeWithSize<Any, Five>:
        print("This is five")
    case is TypeWithSize<Any, Six>:
        print("This is six")
    default:
        print("This is not supported")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was specifically trying to avoid a lot of standalone separate types directly.

Comment: Yes I know but that can't be done as far as I know.

Comment: enums make more sense for phantom types. You don’t need to instantiate them.